# Jenkins: All post-build actions appear twice - no SVN tagging

Tags: svn, hudson, jenkins

We have some Jenkins (was formerly a Hudson system) jobs running.
Now, we saw that all of a sudden most of the post build actions appear twice: [image]
Additionally, if Subversion tagging for successful build is selected, it won't do the tagging anymore because it's deselected again and the input fields go back to default if configuration is reopened (no matter if one or both of the same post build action is selected).

Has anyone had this strange behaviour as well and can tell me how to get rid of it?

Comment: What happens if you uncheck the post-build actions? Does it still perform the actions one time?

Comment: @Sagar Well as I said, in the case of SVN post build action it won't do the tagging, no matter if none, one of them or both are checked. I would like to know how to get rid of the doubled lines?

Comment: Oh the actions themselves. Not the result of the actions - just saw the picture carefully. 
Have you tried deleting and re-downloading the plugins? Also check to make sure there is only one copy of each of the plugins in the ${HUDSON_HOME}/plugins folder.

Comment: @Sagar: Thanks a lot, it was solved after re-downloading (or updating) the plugin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had the problem again, I'd like to add my previously stated comment as answer - after updating all plugins, the problem was solved and every option was listed only once.